# convert regex string to regex object in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting `regex` string from json object (yes its dynamic and will be always be string) i want to test this with textbox value.

But even if i pass valid input text it does not pass `regex` condition

code :

```
var pattern = "/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/";
var str = "Some Name";
pattern = new RegExp(pattern);
if(pattern.test(str))
{
    alert('valid');
}
else
{
    alert('invalid');
}
```

Fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/wn9scv3m/

Comment: It's expecting a space at the end of each word. if `Name` had a trailing space it would pass

Comment: @Derek It does not need a space at the end.[] mean any character from the box.Doesnt matter the sequence.

Comment: You're right, I was seeing the `[]` as `()` for some reason. See my answer for a working regex solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Two problems:

- You need to escape the backslash.
- You need to remove the forward slashes on the beginning and end of string.

Corrected code:

```
var pattern = "^[A-Za-z\\s]+$";
var str = "Some Name";
pattern = new RegExp(pattern);
if(pattern.test(str))
{
    alert('valid');
}
else
{
    alert('invalid');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wn9scv3m/3/

Comment: For completion, I would also add that flags can be passed as a second argument to `new RegExp`. So for e.g. `/[a-z]+/i` you could pass `new RegExp("[a-z]+", "i")`.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`regex-parser`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/regex-parser.js):

```js
const parseRegex = require("regex-parser")

parseRegex("/^hi$/g")
// => /^hi$/g
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wn9scv3m/9/):

```
var pattern = /^[(\w)|(\s)]+$/; // using / regex constructor...
var altPattern = "^[(\w)|(\s)]+$"; // using quotes and new RegEx() syntax...
var regex = new RegExp(altPattern);
var str = "Some Name";
if (str.match(pattern) != null && regex.test(str) != null) { // check using both methods
    alert('valid');
}
else {
    alert('invalid');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions you are combining two methods to declare RegExp. If you are using the string variant, then don't include the "/" character before and after the expression, example:

```
var pattern = "^[A-Za-z\s]+$";
pattern = new RegExp(pattern);
```

If you like the /regexp/ form better, then use it without quotes:

```
pattern = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
```

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```
var str1 = "SomeName"; //true
var str2 = "SomeName123"; //false

function MyRegex(val) { 
    var pattern = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
    var match = pattern.exec(val);
    return match !== null && match[0] === val;
} 

alert(MyRegex(str1));
alert(MyRegex(str2));
```

Comment: The pattern input is `var pattern = "/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/";` So there is no `exec()` function for strings.